# Time and Space Complexity of Nested loop

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

Please consider the following algorithm -

```
for( j = 1; j < n ; j = j * 3)
{
    for( k = 1 ; k <= n ; k = k + 2 )
    {
      r = i + j + k ;

    System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

How is the time and space complexity found for this?

Comment: The time complexity is O(n^2), for space you have O(1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop will have log<sub>3</sub> n iterations, the inner loop will have n / 2 iterations (2 is a constant and can be ignored), thus time complexity is `O(N log N)`.

The space complexity is O(1) because no arrays/lists is created here with regard to N.